# line 7 error BC30311: Value of type 'String()' cannot be converted to 'String' and line 26 & 29 VerifyUsername and VerifyPassword no return value?

Tags: vb.net

[image]

error BC30311: Value of type 'String()' cannot be converted to 'String'.
warning BC42353: Function 'VerifyUsername' doesn't return a value on all code paths. Are you missing a 'Return' statement?

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your post to embed the actual code instead of a picture of it. Cheers!

Comment: You see where there is no code in the `VerifyUsername` function, and so no `Return` statement in there? That's what it is upset about for the second error.

Answer (score 1):

The `VerifyUsername` function accepts a `String` parameter, but the code is passing `arrUsernames()`, an *array* of strings. Same with the `VerifyPassword` function; it accepts a `String` parameter, but the code is giving it another array.

In order to be valid, the argument given to each function must be a `String`, not an array. Consider passing the `username` and `password` parameter values that the `Login` method is accepting, for example.

[image: useless screenshot of the code]

But then the code still won't compile, because the two functions need to `Return` a `Boolean` value in all code paths. For example if you implement the methods and there's an `If` conditional block where you return `True`, make sure the function also returns `False` when the condition isn't met.

Answer (score 0):

Use one name only, not an array, like (for user "Manager"):

```
VerifyUsername(arrUsernames(2))
```